# Rails gem "handles_sortable_columns": Sorting on associations??

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, associations

I saw the closed issue that another user submitted on their github issues page (https://github.com/dadooda/handles_sortable_columns/issues/7) , and I tried doing something similar, but it doesn't work for me.

Course belongs_to category 
Category has_many courses

```
  #View
 <%= sortable_column "Category", column: "category_title" %>


##Courses Controller
 def index
     order = sortable_column_order do |column, direction|
       case column
       when "category_title"
         "category.title #{direction}" 
       end
     end
     if params[:query].blank? 
       @courses = current_account.courses.order(order).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
     else 
       @courses = current_account.courses.search_by_content(params[:query]).order(order).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
     end
   end
```

Error message:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories"
LINE 1: ...urses"  WHERE "courses"."account_id" = 2 ORDER BY categories...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "courses".* FROM "courses"  WHERE "courses"."account_id" = 2 ORDER BY categories.title asc LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0

==============================
Also, how would I be able to use the methods I defined in my models? 
i.e. test.average_score
=> average_score is not saved in a table but is calculuted in the test.rb model

Comment: your are trying to sort the table categories but on the model courses. include the missing table in your query with `courses.include( :categories )`. maybe it is `includes` :)

Comment: So like this? "include(:categories).category.title #{direction}"  
Thanks for answering by the way :)